# Is their any class/classes inside java root package

Tags: java, package

The below code has no compilation error:-

```
import java.*;
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){

    }
}
```

My question is does the package named java only includes sub-packages or it also includes any class/classes. If yes then which class(s). If no then why we are able to import it.

Comment: Why do you ask?

Comment: Why should we be disallowed to wildcard import an empty package?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no class directly under `java`. All the JDK's classes are under subpackages.

Having an empty package (or a package with no classeses in it) is perfectly legal in Java. You can import all the classes in it (which is no classes) with the `*` syntax. This isn't wrong - it's just pointless.